# Infinite FlatList problem - React Native , Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am using Expo for developing react-native applications.
I want to make an Infinite list, but every time `onEndReached` event is fired, `FlatList` is **refreshed** automatically **scrolls to the top** of the page!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [config, setConfig] = useState({
    result: [],
    page: 0
  });

  async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.2.49:3500/q", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ page: config.page })
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    setConfig({
      result: [...config.result, ...data],
      page: config.page++
    });
  }

  const onEndReached = async () => {
    await setConfig({
      page: config.page++
    });
    fetchData();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Current Page : {config.page}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={config.result}
        renderItem={o => <Text>X :{o.item.t.c}</Text>}
        keyExtractor={item => item._id}
        onEndReached={() => onEndReached()}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
      ></FlatList>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setConfig` twice, before calling `fetchData` and after a successful API request. Which triggers a rerender.

I refactored your code, try this.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  NativeSyntheticEvent,
  NativeScrollEvent,
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [config, setConfig] = useState({
    result: [],
    page: 0,
  });

  const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    async function runFetch() {
      const response = await fetch('http://192.168.2.49:3500/q', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ page: config.page }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      setConfig({
        result: [...config.result, ...data],
        page: config.page++,
      });
    }

    runFetch();
  }, [config.page, config.result]);

  const onEndReached = useCallback(() => fetchData(), [fetchData]);

  const onScroll = useCallback(
    e => setIsScrolled(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 0),
    [],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Current Page : {config.page}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={config.result}
        keyExtractor={item => item._id}
        onEndReached={onEndReached}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        renderItem={o => <Text>X :{o.item.t.c}</Text>}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still, have the problem. would you please explain more about your solution ?!

Comment: @Mironline can you provide me an Expo snack so that I can help you better? Thank you

Comment: You fixed the problem, but if you add a `log` to this code, you can see the `fetchData()` is called ***several times*** because of the `callback` function!

Comment: @Mironline I updated the code. Notice the `onScroll` FlatList props added. I've also added `isScrolled` state, to ensure that the user actually scrolled the list, this will prevent `fetchData` multiple execution.

Comment: I tried to add your code into `Snack`. It seems that we have infinite loop! would you please send me a `Snack` url?

Comment: I am about to sleep, can you try to set the threshold to zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206147/discussion-between-karlmarxlopez-and-mironline).